# C# / Mono unit tests on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, macos, unit-testing, mono, tdd

I'm trying to migrate my C# development process from Windows / Visual Studio 2010 to Mac OS X / Monodevelop. And I am wondering if is there any good unit testing framework that will fit my needs?

It would be nice if it will work on Windows / Mac / Ubuntu in the same time.

I've checked obvious options as NUnit and MSTest but the first has executable for Windows only (or I haven't found Mac version yet) and the second is tightly integrated with Studio, with no such application for Mac either.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NUnit support is built into MonoDevelop along with an integrated runner.  I've never tried development and test in VS and Mono against the same solution or project,  could be tricky depending on the project type.

I would expect the tests to continue running subject to the NUnit feature(s) being available across both platforms.  Syntactically they are of course the same `[TestFixture] [Test]` etc

Comment: Ah! So I don't need to have a standalone Nunit runner for Mac! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Mono ships nunit already prepackaged on OSX, so the easy way is to use that.